# Gettting the same instance of the activity from background to foreground in Android

Tags: android, instance, lifecycle, restart

I have an activity that starts a service in its onCreate() method, and then programatically calls the home screen, that is, the onStop() method gets called on the activity, and it goes into background.

I want that same instance to come to foreground. From the things that i have searched, it looks like this can only be done manually, but i want to do this programatically, be it from the activity or the service.

I do not want to recreate another instance of the same activity by calling a new intent.

So basically the question is, i want to go to onStart() from onStop(), and this is perfectly possible by looking at the android lifecycle. I just want to do this programtically.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.(:

Comment: Questions like this tend to imply, "I don't want to have to do all the work of saving/re-creating the instance state of my Activity, so give me the lazy way instead." So I respectfully ask, what is the reason for wanting to do this? :)

Comment: Thanks for replying.:). I am not able to accomplish this using saved state as well. I save the state when the activity goes into background. But when i create a new instance of the activity through the service, the bundle in the onCreate method is still empty.